# Структура для длинной арифметики

Tags: c#, biginteger, длинная-арифметика

Как устроена структура `BigInteger` в `System.Numerics`?
Почему я могу присвоить ей литерал, сделать инкремент, складывать две структуры через `+`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в коде этой структуры перегружены операторы инкремента/декремента, арифметические и логические операторы, а также операторы явного и неявного приведения к основным числовым типам (что как раз позволяет присваивать ей литералы числовых типов).

Вот например как там перегружен оператор +:

```
    public static BigInteger operator +(BigInteger left, BigInteger right)
    {
        left.AssertValid();
        right.AssertValid();

        if (right.IsZero) return left;
        if (left.IsZero) return right;

        int sign1 = +1;
        int sign2 = +1;
        BigIntegerBuilder reg1 = new BigIntegerBuilder(left, ref sign1);
        BigIntegerBuilder reg2 = new BigIntegerBuilder(right, ref sign2);

        if (sign1 == sign2)
            reg1.Add(ref reg2);
        else
            reg1.Sub(ref sign1, ref reg2);

        return reg1.GetInteger(sign1);
    }
```

Благодаря этой перегрузке вы можете складывать два `BigInteger` с помощью обычного оператора +, а не писать для него собственные методы типа `Add` (привет, java).

Всё остальное, если интересно, можете почитать [вот здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs)